# Issue with Struts2 chaining to same method of same class

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, action, chaining

I am upgrading my software from Strtus2 version 2.0.11.1 to version 2.3.15.3. Chaining was working properly with previous version. But after upgrade it is failing in following case :

```
<action name="first_action" class="My_Same_Class">
    <result name="success" type="chain">second_action</result>
    <interceptor-ref name="servletConfig" />
    <interceptor-ref name="staticParams"/>
    <param name="A">37</param>
    <param name="B">1</param>
    <param name="C">0</param>
    <param name="result">result1</param>
</action>

<action name="second_action" class="My_Same_Class">
    <result name="success">/web/jsp/output.jsp</result>
    <interceptor-ref name="servletConfig" />
    <interceptor-ref name="staticParams"/>
    <param name="A">38</param>
    <param name="B">1</param>
    <param name="C">0</param>
    <param name="result">result2</param>
</action>
```

I am passing the same class name in both the actions which are chained one after another. on output.jsp it is displaying result1 but not result2. Even from logs I can see that it only called the 'My_Action_Class' once and only fetched result1.

As per other threads on stack overflow I tried to replace chaining with 'redirectAction' but thats also not working as expected in this case.

Comment: Is it worked in previous version ? In this way ?

Comment: Yes it did. But after upgrade it stopped working.

Answer (score 1):

you can do one method for each action

```
<action name="first_action" class="My_Same_Class" method="firts">
<result name="success" type="chain">second_action</result>
<interceptor-ref name="servletConfig" />
<interceptor-ref name="staticParams"/>
<param name="A">37</param>
<param name="B">1</param>
<param name="C">0</param>
<param name="result">result1</param>
</action>

<action name="second_action" class="My_Same_Class" method="second">
    <result name="success">/web/jsp/output.jsp</result>
    <interceptor-ref name="servletConfig" />
    <interceptor-ref name="staticParams"/>
    <param name="A">38</param>
    <param name="B">1</param>
    <param name="C">0</param>
    <param name="result">result2</param>
</action>
```

and in your My_Same_Class create those methods.

```
public String firts() throws Exception
{
   //your code 
   return SUCCESS;
 }
 public String second() throws Exception
{
   //your code 
   return SUCCESS;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I could figure out a way to address this issue.

I wrote my own interceptor and sent the parameters to the interceptor instead of sending it to class directly.Then through the interceptor I set parameters on valueStack which in turn set it to class variables. Just make sure to have getters and setters for the parameters you are sending to the interceptor.

So, from struts.xml, I send parameters to the interceptor like this :

```
<action name="first_action" class="My_Same_Class">
    <result name="success" type="chain">second_action</result>
    <interceptor-ref name="servletConfig" />
    <interceptor-ref name="staticParams"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="myParamsInterceptor">
        <param name="A">37</param>
        <param name="B">1</param>
        <param name="C">0</param>
        <param name="result">result1</param>
    </interceptor-ref>
</action>
```

In the myParamsInterceptor use following code to push the parameters on the valueStack which will be set to action class variables by struts.

```
ActionContext.getContext().getValueStack().setValue("A",this.getA());
```

I used the same interceptor everywhere I was using the same class and it worked for me.